# Writing a static value returning method In Dll?

Tags: c++

I wrote a custom Memory Manager and override global new and delete.
In order to get a memery manager singleton , I Wrote a function that  return a static refernce instance in dll.  something wrong.

```
//override function
FORCEINLINE void* operator new[](size_t uiSize)
{
    return GEngine::GMemObject::GetMemManager().Allocate((unsigned int)uiSize, 0, true);
}

//get static value reference function
GDebugMemManager& GMemObject::GetMemManager()
{
    static GDebugMemManager debug_manager;
    return debug_manager;
}

//use code
GTempString(unsigned int len) 
{
    str = G_NEW T[len];
    OutputDebugString(TEXT("new a GTempString\n"));
}
```

It have no wrong before it runs into function *GetMemManager*...But when it tries to return,It does't work!!just like entering an endless loop... I have no idea.

[the auto window change to gray,the program is running but not to next step]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwHle.png)

PS:

`GetMemManager` constructor can run successfully

I try to use a global GDebugMemManager value,It can run...

Comment: We cannot help you without knowing what the `GDebugMemManager` constructor does. Have you tried using your debugger to "step into" the line with `static` or putting a breakpoint on the constructor?

Comment: I try to use a global `GDebugMemManager`  value.It can run...the constructor is running successfully...  : (